# Chainlink - where are adapter keywords specified?

Tags: solidity, chainlink

I watched a tutorial video [here](https://docs.chain.link/docs/advanced-tutorial/). In the following example, we use `req.addInt("times", 100);`

Where are the adapter references specified (in this case, `"times"`)? On market.link, I'm unable to see any reference to this identifier. How does one usually find these adapter references, such as `"times"`?

```
function requestPrice()
  public
{
  Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(jobId, this, this.fulfill.selector);

  req.addInt("times", 100);

  sendChainlinkRequest(req, LINK * 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the written tutorial, in the [Core Adapters](https://docs.chain.link/docs/advanced-tutorial/#core-adapters) section, take a look at step 3: [multiply](https://docs.chain.link/docs/core-adapters/#multiply).

You will se that the core adapter [multiply](https://docs.chain.link/docs/core-adapters/#multiply) requires the parameter "times", specified in the documentation, which is the number of times it will be multiplied.

Answer (score 0):

[Version 1 Core Adapters have been removed.](https://docs.chain.link/docs/core-adapters/#multiply) See documentation for Version 2 adapters [here](https://docs.chain.link/docs/tasks/). And here's the link for the [Version 2 multiply](https://docs.chain.link/docs/jobs/task-types/multiply/).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/70321)